# HTML Scraping when there are no html tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the elevation data, and start and end pass times from this [website](https://www.n2yo.com/passes/?s=39090&a=1).
So far I have looked at the source code and been unable to use Beautiful Soup to get what I want as the source code doesn't have any tags around the information I am interested in. That information is contained in functions by the name of spStart, and it's corresponding arguments. I had a go at using selenium to obtain the Javascript processed code, but I ended up getting the same as the source code on the page and now I'm stuck.

Here is my attempt at using selenium:

```
import datetime
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service
from lxml import html


try:
    #Launching chrome in headless mode to access inspect element code''
    service = service.Service('/correct_path/chromedriver.exe')
    chrome_options = Options()  
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'/correct_path/chromedriver.exe')  
    driver.get("https://www.n2yo.com/passes/?s=39090&a=1") 
    print("Chrome Browser Initialized in Headless Mode")

    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.innerHTML;"), "lxml")
    print(soup)

   
 
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    driver.quit()
    print("Driver Exited")
```

When I run this code it gives me the html that I see when using the "view source" option in chrome. I was under the impression that by using selenium to get the source this way, I would be seeing what is available when using the "inspect element" option on the same page in chrome.

Would someone mind explaining where I'm going wrong and suggesting a feasible approach to get the data I want, possibly with an explained example? I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

No is not the same, `Inspect Element` inspects the [`DOM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), the source page although is practically the original seed page for the [`DOM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), the [`DOM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) can  dynamically change and usually changes by JS code, 
 sometimes quite dramatically. Also you will notice that `Inspect Element` shows the shadow elements which the source show not.

To see how dramatic is the difference visit `chrome://settings/` and click `Inspect element` and then look at the `View page source` and compare.

You should target the element after has loaded and take `arguments[0]` and not the entire page via `document`

```
html_of_interest=driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].innerHTML',element)
sel_soup=BeautifulSoup(html_of_interest, 'lxml')
```

This has 2 practical cases:

### 1

the element is not yet loaded in the DOM and you need to wait for the element:

```
browser.get("url")
sleep(experimental) # usually get will finish only after the page is loaded but sometimes there is some JS woo running after on load time

try:
    element= WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'your_id_of_interest')))
    print "element is ready do the thing!"
    html_of_interest=driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].innerHTML',element)
    sel_soup=BeautifulSoup(html_of_interest, 'html.parser')
except TimeoutException:
    print "Somethings wrong!"
```

### 2

the element is in a shadow root and you need to expand first the shadow root, probably not your situation but I will mention it here since it is relevant for future reference. ex:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root

driver.get("chrome://settings")
root1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('settings-ui')

html_of_interest=driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].innerHTML',root1)
sel_soup=BeautifulSoup(html_of_interest, 'html.parser')
sel_soup# empty root not expande

shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)

html_of_interest=driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].innerHTML',shadow_root1)
sel_soup=BeautifulSoup(html_of_interest, 'html.parser')
sel_soup
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very detailed explanation and also worked for me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what data from that page you are interested in. However, If the tabular data you are after then the below script is worth trying for:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from contextlib import closing
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.n2yo.com/passes/?s=39090&a=1"

chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

with closing(Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)) as driver:
    driver.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    for items in soup.select("#passestable tr"):
        data = [item.text for item in items.select("th,td")]
        print(data)
```

Partial output:

```
['Start ', 'Max altitude', 'End ', 'All passes']
['Date, Local time', 'Az', 'Local time', 'Az', 'El', 'Local time', 'Mag ', 'Info']
['20-Feb 19:17', 'N13°', '19:25', 'E76°', '81°', '19:32', 'S191°', '-', 'Map and details']
['21-Feb 06:24', 'SSE151°', '06:31', 'E79°', '43°', '06:38', 'N358°', '-', 'Map and details']
```